# Qt5 Python скопировать текст из line edit

Tags: python, pyqt5, clipboard

подскажите как можно скопировать сформированный текст из объекта line edit в PyQt5. Можно разными способами либо может можно как то выдилить мышкой и скопировать, либо как то назначить кнопку рядом с полем чтобы копировать в буфер.
Вот эти данные из формы atan.py нужно скопировать в буфер:

```
self.label_result
self.label_result_2
self.label_result_3
```

main.py

```
import sys, math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from atan import Ui_MainWindow


class Atan(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Atan, self).__init__()
        self.atan = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.atan.setupUi(self)
        self.init_atan()

    def init_atan(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Вычисление арктангенса')
        self.atan.num_1.setPlaceholderText('Введите первое значение')
        self.atan.num_2.setPlaceholderText('Введите второе значение')
        self.atan.btn_result.clicked.connect(self.converter)
      

    def converter(self):
        num_1 = float(self.atan.num_1.text())
        num_2 = float(self.atan.num_2.text())

        out_atan = round(math.degrees(math.atan((num_1 / num_2))), 5)
        out_cos = round(math.cos(out_atan * math.pi / 180), 5)
        out_result = round((num_2 / out_cos), 5)

        self.atan.label_result.setText(str(out_atan))
        self.atan.label_result_2.setText(str(out_cos))
        self.atan.label_result_3.setText(str(out_result))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = Atan()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

atan.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 216)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_result = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 120, 121, 31))
        self.btn_result.setObjectName("btn_result")
        self.num_1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.num_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 191, 31))
        self.num_1.setText("")
        self.num_1.setObjectName("num_1")
        self.num_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.num_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 191, 31))
        self.num_2.setText("")
        self.num_2.setObjectName("num_2")
        self.label_result = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 30, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_result.setFont(font)
        self.label_result.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_result.setText("")
        self.label_result.setObjectName("label_result")
        self.label_result_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_result_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 70, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_result_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_result_2.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_result_2.setText("")
        self.label_result_2.setObjectName("label_result_2")
        self.label_result_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_result_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 110, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_result_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_result_3.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_result_3.setText("")
        self.label_result_3.setObjectName("label_result_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 30, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 70, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 110, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычисление арктангенса"))
        self.btn_result.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычислить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Арктангенс (град)"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Косинус арктангенса"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Результат:"))
```

Comment: а что вы дальше собираетесь делать с этими скопированными данными ?

Comment: да просто скопировать в системный буфер чтобы потом вставить в документ какой нибудь. Я почитал что можно вроде как поставить кнопки возле каждого line edit которые будут посылать сигнал clicked() а связанный слот будет вызывать метод copy() Не знаю так ли это.

Comment: Вот добавил строку: self.atan.copy.clicked.connect(self.atan.label_result.clear) но она только очищает line edit а copy такого слота почему то нет. Ошибка 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: Вопросе вы спрашиваете как скопировать `lineEdit` и тут же уточняете, что вам надо скопировать `label`. Уточните, что вы хотите скопировать.

Comment: Вопрос разрешился, то я тупил, почему то пытался скопировать qlabel хотя нужно было заменить объекты на lineedit.